# Significato di "girotondo" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning

Qualche giorno fa, ho messo la radio (RAI Radio 3 classica) e ho ascoltato la musica che appare nei titoli di testa del film *Uccellacci e uccellini* (testo di Pasolini?), una canzone composta da Ennio Morricone che ho sempre trovato molto divertente. Il suo testo si può leggere su [questo sito web](http://www.chimai.com/index.cfm?module=MUS&mode=DET&id=623). La mia domanda fa riferimento a questo passo (grassetto mio):

> Trovati per le strade del mondo 
>   tutti gli altri attori 
>   da Femi Benussi a Vittorio Vittori 
>   Nel triste **girotondo** 
>   nel lieto **girotondo** 
>   Luigi Scaccianoce architettò 
>   Danilo Donati acconciò 
>   Nino Baragli montò e rimontò 
>   [...]

Cercando sui dizionari, ho visto che la parola "girotondo" può avere diverse accezioni; per esempio, sul *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana* si trova [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000860.jpg) e [qui](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI06/00000861.jpg). Tuttavia, non riesco a capire a quale si riferisca l'uso che se ne fa nel passaggio sopra citato. Potrebbe avere a che vedere con il fatto di girare il film?

Comment: Cosa intendesse per “girotondo” lo può dire solo chi ha scritto il testo. La mia impressione è che si riferisca metaforicamente alla vita i cui cicli possono far venire in mente dei girotondi.

Comment: Credo che Pasolini qui tenga insieme vari significati: quello del gioco di girare in tondo (senza uno scopo preciso se non quello di giocare), quello di girare il film (come hai intuito), quello della spensieratezza infantile…

Comment: @Gio: Se veramente è così, forse si dovrebbe chiudere la domanda.

Comment: @Gio: Allora spero i vostri voti per chiudere la domanda.

Comment: @Gio: Ho cercato di riaprire il dibattito con [questa risposta su Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1419/707).